# how to align horizontally using CSS

Tags: php, jquery, css

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
    $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript("components/com_jea/views/property/tmpl/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js");
    $document->addScript("components/com_jea/views/property/tmpl/lib/jquery.ad-gallery.js");
    $document->addScript("components/com_jea/views/property/tmpl/lib/inside.js");
    $document->addStyleSheet("components/com_jea/views/property/tmpl/lib/jquery.ad-gallery.css");
    $document->addStyleSheet("components/com_jea/views/property/tmpl/lib/inside.css");  
    if (!is_array($this->row->images)) {
        return ;
    }

    $mainImage = array_shift($this->row->images);


    JHTML::_('behavior.modal', 'a.jea_modal', array('onOpen' => '\onOpenSqueezebox'));
    ?>


     <body>
      <div id="container">


        <div id="gallery" class="ad-gallery">
          <div class="ad-image-wrapper">
          </div>
          <div class="ad-controls">
          </div>
          <div class="ad-nav">
            <div class="ad-thumbs">
              <ul class="ad-thumb-list">
                <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $mainImage->URL ?>" >
                <img src="<?php echo $mainImage->mediumURL ?>" width="100px" height="50px" alt="<?php echo $mainImage->title ?>" title="<?php echo $mainImage->description ?>"  />
            </a>
        </li>


            <li class="image<?php echo $num; ?>">
             <?php if( !empty($this->row->images)): ?>
                <?php foreach($this->row->images as $num => $image) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $image->URL ?>" >
                        <img  src="<?php echo $image->mediumURL ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->title ?>" width="100px" height="50px" title="<?php echo $image->description ?>"  />
                    </a>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </li>
        <?php endif ?>
           </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    </body>
```

**CSS code**

```
 * {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;

  }
  select, input, textarea {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  #container {
   line-height:0px !important;
    border:1px solid #DEE5EB;
  }




  h2 {
    margin-top: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #dedede;
  }
  h3 {
    margin-top: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .example {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-image:url(list-style.gif);
  }
  pre {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", Verdana;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  code {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", Verdana;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #gallery {
    padding: 30px;
    background: #F8FAFB;
  }
```

Using above cods the output [is this](http://bluewingholidays.com/index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id=2%3amodern-03-bedroom-beach-house-hikkaduwa#ad-image-3)

how to align horizontally using CSS

Comment: What do you want to align horizontally? If it is the gallery, just add margin: 0 auto;

Comment: did you see the out put.those thumbnails are now in vertically.i want to align it horizontally like this http://bluewingholidays.com/components/com_jea/views/property/tmpl/example/example.html

Comment: I see, well it looks like the list elements are correctly floated, but the second one contains 7 images wrapped in a-tags. You should add float: left; to them as well: .ad-gallery .ad-thumbs li a { float:left; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why:

[image: Deveoper Tools Screenshot]

[Link to fullsize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEG8d.png)

Your `<a>` tags are inside the same `<li>` tag, that's why they appear like that. Put `<li class="image<?php echo $num; ?>">` inside your `foreach` loop.

```
<?php if(!empty($this->row->images)): ?>
    <?php foreach($this->row->images as $num => $image): ?>
        <li class="image<?php echo $num; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $image->URL ?>" >
                <img  src="<?php echo $image->mediumURL ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->title ?>" width="100px" height="50px" title="<?php echo $image->description ?>"  />
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: <li class="image<?php echo $num; ?>"> is not working .but now first image is small than other ones

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the live test?

Comment: http://bluewingholidays.com/index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id=2%3amodern-03-bedroom-beach-house-hikkaduwa#ad-image-2

Comment: and i want a big images as previews .how will i do that

Comment: Have you changed the code as I've explained above? The `<a>` elements are still inside the same `<li>` (screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ElMUZ.png ), it's just that now they are floated to the left. To make the first one the same size as the others, you'll have to set its `width` (`width: 133px;`).

Comment: Dear Ana when i paste you code it will appear php syntax error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH in /home/bluewi5/public_html/components/com_jea/views/property/tmpl/default_gallery.php on line 58

Comment: width (width: 133px; i added  this>now it's ok Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to big preview images ?

Comment: If you mean the larger image above the thumbnails, it's shown as big as it really is - `320px × 240px`. The weird thing is that, at the same time, you're using `500px` images for the thumbnails. So maybe you should use the `URL` for the `img` `src` and the `mediumURL` for the `a` `href`. Do you have any larger versions? Could you do a `var_dump($image)` inside the `foreach` in that case?

Answer (score 0):

For `ul` with class `ad-thumb-list` make width much more bigger and that's all.